# Pixel distances depending on contour

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a binary image in opencv where the outline of an object is shown. My boss told me that there is a function in OpenCV that measures the minimum distance between all the pixels of the image and the outline, could someone tell me what that function would be ?. Or if there is a kernel that can be used to perform a convolution for that image?

To get an idea of ​​what my goal is: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's `cv2.distanceTransform` to calc the distance from the contour.

```
distanceTransform(...)
    distanceTransform(src, distanceType, maskSize[, dst[, dstType]]) -> dst
    .   @overload
    .   @param src 8-bit, single-channel (binary) source image.
    .   @param dst Output image with calculated distances. It is a 8-bit or 32-bit floating-point,
    .   single-channel image of the same size as src .
    .   @param distanceType Type of distance, see #DistanceTypes
    .   @param maskSize Size of the distance transform mask, see #DistanceTransformMasks. In case of the
    .   #DIST_L1 or #DIST_C distance type, the parameter is forced to 3 because a \f$3\times 3\f$ mask gives
    .   the same result as \f$5\times 5\f$ or any larger aperture.
    .   @param dstType Type of output image. It can be CV_8U or CV_32F. Type CV_8U can be used only for
    .   the first variant of the function and distanceType == #DIST_L1.
```

A simple example (in python) is here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

img = np.zeros((400, 800), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(img, (300, 200), 100, (255,0,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.circle(img, (500, 200), 100, (255,0,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
img = 255 - img
#cv2.imshow("x", img);cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(img, cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=0)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.subplot(212)
plt.imshow(dist)
plt.show()
```

[image]

A C++ example is here:

[Contour width measurement along its entire lendth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910428/contour-width-measurement-along-its-entire-lendth/47918748#47918748)

Comment: Might be pertinent to mention the reason for the inversion of the image :)

Comment: Many op in OpenCV process on the nonzero region, such as `findContours`, and this `distanceTransform`. First draw white (nozero) on black(zero), then invert to set target regions (to be calc distance) to nozero. Or you can try with `img = 255- img` commented.